GA4 Events in Big Query expiring after 60 days even after adding billing details and setting table expiry to "Never"
trying to backup GA4 Data in Big Query, data stream events are pulling in however events are expiring after 60 days despite upgrading from Sanbox and setting the Big Query Table expiry to "Never"
Has anybody experienced a similar issue and know why this is happening?

I suspect that the Never only apply to new tables created after you changed the settings

I figured it out, I changed the default expiration date for the main data set but I also needed to change the expiration date for the individual existing tables. All new tables will have the new expiration date but old tables will need to be changed manually (I had to go through almost 60 tables manually to change the date)
